# Listen to a key/button press from a BT remote control/device connected to an iPhone (via bluetooth)

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, keyboard

We have a requirement to develop an app that will be controlled by a remote control Bluetooth device.
The device/remote is already working with Android, and now we need to find a way to get the buttons press events.

**This what I've found out so far:**

- I've tried to connect with CoreBluetooth and only got 2 services: PnP id and battery info so it's not helping us.
- The device isn't in the MFi program so EA framework won't help in this case.
- When connected to an iPhone - the device/remote is triggering 4 system events:

  1. volume up
  2. volume down
  3. mute/unmute
  4. home button

  The problem though, we need to override these actions to our own actions, in addition to listening to other button presses that are currently ignored by the system.
- **I've read numerous Q&As here but haven't found something smilier to our scenario and something actually helpful.**

I'm fully aware that we might need to write some c or c++ code or develop a profile or something similar - I just don't know where to start at this point..

Comment: My best guess is that as well as Pnp and battery info there is a remote control profile of some kind on there but the phone isn't exposing it to you because the OS handles that.  To find out more - get a bluetooth sniffer of some kind so you can see the raw data and if there is an extra profile on there.   Generally you can't do much without being in MFI

Comment: Just to confirm, after you call `peripheral.discoverServices(nil)` - and after you get a callback on the `CBPeripheralDelegate`'s method `peripheral(_:didDiscoverServices:)` you're only getting those two services (PnP id and battery info)? Have you tried discovering any included services as part of those?

Comment: Can it push text into a `UITextField` when linked to iPhone? Example - Open Notes.app in iPhone, open a new note, tap into note so that it starts showing keyboard (if it doesn't - don't worry) - Try sending a few commands / presses from remote control - Do you see text being written into Notes?